# Laravel returns an empty array for a number field

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-blade, htmlspecialchars

When I output results of a query in blade, a numeric field value is returned as an array but if you look at the raw record the value is a 1 or a 0.

Laravel Version: `5.4.36`

Product controller:

```php
  $products = Product::select('id', 'hidden')->take(2)->get();
  return view('products.index', compact('products'));
```

**if I append `->toArray()` to the query the problem goes away.** 
but I shouldn't have to (I think).

Product Model:

```php
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Product extends Model
{
}
```

Data structure:

```php
id: INT(10)
hidden: TINYINT(1)
```

Blade view:

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
  id: {{$product['id']}}<br>
  @if(is_array ($product['hidden']))
    hidden (array): <?=count($product['hidden'])?><br>
  @endif
  record set:  {{$product}}  <br>
@endforeach
```

Output

```php
id: 7339 
hidden (array): 0
record set: {"id":7339,"hidden":0}
id: 7340
hidden (array): 0
record set: {"id":7340,"hidden":1}
```

Comment: Please post the `Product` model.

Comment: But `{{$product['hidden']}}` works?

Comment: no `{{$product['hidden']}}` returns: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Product model added

Comment: What's the result of `{{ dd($product->getAttributes()) }}`?

Comment: array:2 [▼
  "id" => 7339
  "hidden" => 0
]

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: Please, provide more information. How can this `@if(is_array ($product['hidden']))` return true? isn't hidden a `tinyint`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/18403) that has been fixed in Laravel 5.5.

You have to access `hidden` as an object property:

```
{{ $product->hidden }}
```

Comment: Ahh, the answer. Thank you.